# php bin/magento setup:di:compile Errors

Tags: php, magento, installation

when i run php bin/magento setup:di:compile on cmd this error will occur:

**Compilation was started.
Plugin list generation... 8/9 [========================>---]  88% 10 mins 392.0 MiB
In ErrorHandler.php line 61:
Warning: file_put_contents(C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/generated/metadata/primary|global|plugin-list.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp
\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php on line 415
setup:di:compile**

Then I see solution on internet I find that if I replace this
`$cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;`
with
`$cacheId = implode(‘-’, $this->scopePriorityScheme) . “-” . $this->cacheId;`

then this error will resolve but a new error will accrue which is :

**Deprecated Functionality: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php on line 159**

and this error resolves when I discard my all previous changes and then again first error occurred

Comment: So, fix the 2nd error, do not revert the changes.

Comment: the solution of 2nd error is this chages $cacheId = implode(‘-’, $this->scopePriorityScheme) . “-” . $this->cacheId; to $cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;
which i change for resolve first error.

Comment: no, the solution of 2nd error is not reverting the change, but fixing "Deprecated Functionality" warning you are getting - it's pretty self explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line

```
$cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;
```

with the following one:

```
$cacheId = implode('-', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "-" . $this->cacheId;
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. I believe it would greatly help everyone if you could explain why and how this answer solves the OP's problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
$cacheId = implode(‘-’, $this->scopePriorityScheme) . “-” . $this->cacheId;
```

I copy this line from a website, When I copy it then '' automatically changes to ‘’ and "" changes to  “” thatsway error occurred.
use this:

```
$cacheId = implode('-', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "-" . $this->cacheId;
```

Thanks